# Jenkins: How to keep container running and copy artifacts out of container to host machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Here is what I am doing and hope to achieve

1. I Run docker container.
2. Inside container I run the tests.
3. And finally I would like to copy the test artifacts out of the container before closing the container.

At the moment I am using it like this and first 2 steps work fine

```
 stage('Pulling Docker Image'){
            steps{
                echo "Pulling Docker Image"
                script{
                  docker.withRegistry("url", "credentials"){
                      docker.image(<image>).inside(<arguments>->c{
                       //run tests inside container
                      }
                  }
                }
         }
 }
 post{
   always{
     docker cp <container>:/test_result:/test_result_store/
     docker stop <container>
     docker rm <container>
   }
```

But with this approach the container is closing and getting removed, before post step is invoked.

I looked at [documentation](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow) where it mentions `run` and `withRun` option which returns container handle.
So I modified the code like this

```
 stage('Pulling Docker Image'){
            steps{
                echo "Pulling Docker Image & Running Tests"
                script{
                  docker.withRegistry("url", "credentials"){
                      def container_handle = docker.image(<image>).run(<arguments>->c{
                       //run tests inside container
                      }
                  }
                }
         }
 }
 post{
   always{
     docker cp container_handle:/test_result:/test_result_store/
     docker stop container_handle
     docker rm container_handle
   }
```

but here `container_handle` seems to be invalid reference inside `post` step, also test is not run inside the container.

I would appreciate if one can point out to obvious errors I am doing here.

Also I am planning to save all this to a pipeline script so let me know, if these steps will work as is or some change might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything at all, Jenkins will bind-mount the workspace directory into the container at the same path.  The `docker.inside()` helper will take care of creating, starting, stopping, and destroying the container for you.

```groovy
stage('Running tests in container') {
  docker.withRegistry("url", "credentials") {
    docker.image("image").inside {
      sh "./run_tests.sh"
      // Assume this drops JUnit test results into the current directory
    }
  }
  // outside the container
  junit(testResults: 'test-results.xml')
}
```

You do not need to specify a `-v` bind-mount option; Jenkins provides this for you.  You do not need to manually `docker cp` because Docker has the bind-mount of the workspace directory.

Comment: So at the moment I do following in the arguments `--name mymnt --mount source=${workspace},target=/myapp,type=bind` are you saying I don't need to mount anything at all?

Comment: Right.  If you look at the extended Jenkins logs, you should see the command it runs, and that includes a `docker run -v` bind-mount option already.